# how to loop through an array of jquery objects and .hide() each of them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop through an array of jquery objects I have created that are hidden when clicked. Right now Im not sure where I am going wrong with this and was wondering if anyone could explain what I need to do to make it work?

I have created a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/hd5qa/3/

All advice much appreciated

Kyle

Comment: the reason I have created objects is because I want to use them multiple times

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problems with your fiddle were as follows:

1) You hadn't included the jQuery library.

2) You hadn't closed the `each` loop correctly (missing parenthesis).

3) You were missing the `id` selector `#` from "myButton".

Here's an [updated, working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hd5qa/4/).

Note, however, that you could simply do this:

```
$("#blue, #red, #green, #black, #purple, #orange").hide();
```

Or better, put all of those in a containing parent element, and simply hide that, or use `$("#parent div").hide();`.

You can store the result of that selection in a single variable, rather than the 6 you currently have, as jQuery methods tend to operate on each element in the matched set without the need for a loop.

Comment: Or use a class - no extra tags.

Comment: Yeah, all sorts of better options than storing an array of each element as a separate jQuery object and iterating over that array!

Answer (score 1):

is there a reason you want to do this trough an array of objects?

you could simplify it all by adding your selectors like this:

```
$('#blue, #red, #green, #black, #purple, #orange').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(myArray).each(function(index, element){
    element.hide();
});
```

you may wanna try something like this!

```
var myArray = [$blue, $red, $green, $black, $purple, $orange];

$('#myButton').click(function() {
    $(myArray).each(function(index, element) {
        $(element).hide();
    });

 });
```

You can see it running here:
http://jsfiddle.net/hd5qa/3/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this way:

```
var elements = $("div");
var numOfElements = elemenets.length;
for(var i=0; i<numOfElements; i++) {
    var element = elements.eq(i);
    element.hide();
}
```

Comment: $(".div") would be under the assumption he gave the class 'div' to all his divs. i think you meant $('div') ... but i could be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems:

- You run the code with the MooTools library instead of jQuery.
- You forgot `#` in the selector for the button.
- You forgot a `);` at the end of the `$.each` loop.

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/hd5qa/5/