# jQuery create id's in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to allow a user to enter in a number (i.e. 3 in the first div below) that will decide which div's to show in an output.  I created an array of id's (or so I thought) based on the number entered.  When I alert the array the id's look correct but for some reason when I try and show them in the function below nothing happens.  This is very similar to this post: [how to loop through an array of jquery objects and .hide() each of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706859/how-to-loop-through-an-array-of-jquery-objects-and-hide-each-of-them)  but I can't re-create it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dbeau79/4KzuN/

```
<div id="variable_1">3</div>

<div id="jinja_1" class="jinja">I'm Jinja 1</div>
<div id="jinja_2" class="jinja">I'm Jinja 2</div>
<div id="jinja_3" class="jinja">I'm Jinja 3</div>
<div id="jinja_4" class="jinja">I'm Jinja 4</div>
<div id="jinja_5" class="jinja">I'm Jinja 5</div>
<div id="jinja_6" class="jinja">I'm Jinja 6</div>    

$('.jinja').hide();    
var varStart = 1;
var varEnd = $('#variable_1').text();

var arr = [];

while (varStart <= varEnd) {
arr.push("'#jinja_" + varStart++ + "'");
}

$.each(arr, function () {
//alert(this);
$(this).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this would solve your problem:

```
<div id="variable_1">3</div>

<div id="jinja_1" class="jinja">I'm Jinja 1</div>
<div id="jinja_2" class="jinja">I'm Jinja 2</div>
<div id="jinja_3" class="jinja">I'm Jinja 3</div>
<div id="jinja_4" class="jinja">I'm Jinja 4</div>
<div id="jinja_5" class="jinja">I'm Jinja 5</div>
<div id="jinja_6" class="jinja">I'm Jinja 6</div>    

//$('.jinja').hide();    
var varStart = 1;
var varEnd = $('#variable_1').text();

var arr = [];

while (varStart <= varEnd) {
arr.push("#jinja_" + varStart++ + "");
}

$.each(arr, function (i, elem) {
//alert(this);
$(elem).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you want this:

```
var id = $('#variable_1').text();

$('[id*=jinja_]').hide();

// Step One
$('#jinja_' + id).show(function(){
    $(this).prevAll('div').show();
});

// Step Two
$('[id*=jinja_]').hide();
$('#jinja_' + id).show();
$('#jinja_' + id).prevAll('div').show();
```

Depends on you which one you like to use.

[<kbd>JSFIDDLE</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/5b9vZ/)

Comment: very tidy!  This is a huge help as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a completely different approach: http://jsfiddle.net/4KzuN/13/

```
<input type="number" value="3">

<ul>
    <li>I'm jinja 1</li>
    <li>I'm jinja 2</li>
    <li>I'm jinja 3</li>
    <li>I'm jinja 4</li>
    <li>I'm jinja 5</li>
</ul>

<script>
    $('input').on('keyup', function() {
        $('li').hide();
        $('li').eq(parseInt($(this).val(), 10) - 1).show();
    }).keyup();
</script>
```

Comment: I should've been more clear but what I needed was to show all the elements that were in the array not just the last one.  I like this code though and could use it as well.  Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Just a different approach - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/suVPg/) - not better than another other. Perhaps limited in older browsers.

CSS

```
.jinja {
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
var mynumber = +$('#variable_1').html() + 1;

$('.jinja:nth-child('+ mynumber +')').css('display', 'block');
```